# How to display a different image based on button clicks with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am coding a game for a school project. I have coded it so that I use wasd to move my character. I have four different images: one facing left, one right, one forwards, and one backwards. I need to change the image being displayed as the character based on which button I press. I have a function defining each image, and I try to call that function based on which button is pressed, and then when the button goes back up, I want to display the front facing image again. All it does is every time I press, the corresponding facing image is displayed, goes away, and then the front facing image is displayed and then goes away very quickly. This is just the part that actually deals with the character:

```
howieImg = pygame.image.load('howie front.PNG')
howieImg_back = pygame.image.load('howie back.PNG')
howieImg_left = pygame.image.load('howie left.PNG')
howieImg_right = pygame.image.load('howie right.PNG')

def howie(x, y):
gameDisplay.blit(howieImg, (x, y))
def howie_back(x, y):
gameDisplay.blit(howieImg_back, (x, y))
def howie_left(x, y):
gameDisplay.blit(howieImg_left, (x, y))
def howie_right(x, y):
gameDisplay.blit(howieImg_right, (x, y))

while not gameExit:
        startx = (display_width/2)
        starty = (display_height/2)
        thing_width = 25
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w and y > 0:
                    howie_back(x, y)
                    y_change = -3
                if event.key == pygame.K_s and y < display_height - character_height:
                    howie(x, y)
                    y_change = 3
                if event.key == pygame.K_a and x > 0:
                    howie_left(x, y)
                    x_change = -3
                if event.key == pygame.K_d and x < display_width - character_width:
                    howie_right(x, y)
                    x_change = 3                       
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    howie(x, y)
                    y_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    howie(x, y)
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        y += y_change

        if x > display_width - character_width or x < 0:
            x_change = 0
        if y > display_height - character_height or y < 0:
            y_change = 0

        clock.tick(60)
        gameDisplay.blit(background1Img, [0, 0])
        button1()
        howie(x, y)
        things_collected(collected)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I just updated my code

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of the functions and just store the current image in a variable (`howieImg` in the example below). When the user presses one of the keys, you can simply assign one of the other images to the current image variable.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# These are just replacement images that allowed me to test the code.
# howieImg_front = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
# howieImg_front.fill((0, 0, 255))
# howieImg_back = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
# howieImg_back.fill((255, 255, 0))
# howieImg_left = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
# howieImg_left.fill((255, 0, 0))
# howieImg_right = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
# howieImg_right.fill((0, 255, 0))

howieImg_front = pygame.image.load('howie front.PNG').convert_alpha()
howieImg_back = pygame.image.load('howie back.PNG').convert_alpha()
howieImg_left = pygame.image.load('howie left.PNG').convert_alpha()
howieImg_right = pygame.image.load('howie right.PNG').convert_alpha()

# Assign the current howie image to this variable.
howieImg = howieImg_front

x = 200
y = 300
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gameExit = False
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                howieImg = howieImg_back
                y_change = -3
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                howieImg = howieImg_front
                y_change = 3
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                howieImg = howieImg_left
                x_change = -3
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                howieImg = howieImg_right
                x_change = 3                       
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                howieImg = howieImg_front
                y_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                howieImg = howieImg_front
                x_change = 0

    x += x_change
    y += y_change

    gameDisplay.fill((30, 30, 30))
    # Just blit the current `howieImg`.
    gameDisplay.blit(howieImg, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: can you show what line of code grabs the image from my files?

Comment: Just load your images with `pygame.image.load` when the program starts. Also, call [`convert()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) or `convert_alpha()` to improve the performance (`convert` is a lot faster).

Comment: I am coding my program again because I had too many useless pieces of code and this will get me more organized. But I did take your code and test it and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: My previous code had a boundary system, but for some reason, it does not work with the new code.

Comment: You just have to add these checks again `if x > display_width - character_width or x < 0: x_change = 0`. I only removed them because they were not relevant for the image switching.